# Script generated via appassembler-maven-plugin is not able to find main class in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, appassembler

I have a problem with the start script that I generate with appassembler-maven-plugin.
I have a basic spring-boot application with only one class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ScriptDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScriptDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.home.sziolkow</groupId>
    <artifactId>script-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>script-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                                repackage
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goal>
                        package
                    </goal>
                    <showConsoleWindow>
                        true
                    </showConsoleWindow>
                    <platforms>
                        <platform>unix</platform>
                    </platforms>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>org.home.sziolkow.ScriptDemoApplication</mainClass>
                            <id>app</id>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I run maven with: `mvn package appassembler:assemble`

Package and scripts are generated but when I try to run `./target/appassembler/bin/app`, I get

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.home.sziolkow.ScriptDemoApplication

I tested generated packages and I can start the application without problems with:

```
java -jar ./target/appassembler/repo/org/home/sziolkow/script-demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/script-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having this trouble because of the way Spring Boot is repackaging your JAR, in order to make it an executable JAR. From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar):

> The executable archive cannot be used as a dependency as the exectuable jar format packages application classes in `BOOT-INF/classes`. This means that they cannot be found when the executable jar is used as a dependency.

Essentially, the Spring Boot Maven Plugin repackages your JAR and puts your classes inside `BOOT-INF/classes`, all the JAR dependencies inside `BOOT-INF/lib`, and launches its [`JarLauncher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.html) class as main class, which will search for classes and JARs at those locations.

So you have 2 solutions: do not use Spring Boot to repackage your JAR into an executable JAR, or do not use the Appassembler plugin at all.

#### Without the Appassembler

Since Spring Boot creates an executable JAR for you, generating scripts with the Appassembler plugin is not necessary. Remove the plugin declaration for `appassembler-maven-plugin` and have:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>org.home.sziolkow.ScriptDemoApplication</mainClass>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The only change with your POM is the addition of the `<mainClass>` parameter pointing to your main class, and the removal of the `appassembler-maven-plugin`. When launching `mvn clean package`, you'll be able to launch the generated executable JAR directly with:

```
java -jar target/script-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If the version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in the name of the executable is an issue, you can simply set a `<finalName>` in your POM:

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

and then the executable JAR will be launched with `java -jar target/script-demo.jar`.

#### With the Appassembler

As said before, since Spring Boot `repackage` goal put the classes and JARs inside a `BOOT-INF` folder, we need to get rid of that. So remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin declaration, and have in your POM:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>assemble</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>assemble</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <showConsoleWindow>true</showConsoleWindow>
        <platforms>
          <platform>unix</platform>
        </platforms>
        <programs>
          <program>
            <mainClass>org.home.sziolkow.ScriptDemoApplication</mainClass>
            <id>app</id>
          </program>
        </programs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The difference with your current POM is that the Appassembler is bound to the `package` phase, so that the execution is launched without invoking `appassembler:assemble`. Then, when running `mvn clean package`, you'll be able to start your application using the scripts generated by the Appassembler:

```
./target/appassembler/bin/app
```

Comment: Great! It works. I've decided to get rid of spring-boot-maven-plugin. Thx